# Странное поведение при наборе текста

Tags: клавиатура

Всем привет.
Есть вопрос о том как можно надежнее защитить содержимое http запросов и ответов помимо SSL.
Часто наблюдаю подмену символов при наборе текста (например в соц. сети фейсбук).
Такое впечатление, что мой траффик обрабатывают через  прокси.

Как с этим бороться? Плиз хелп.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Отключи все равсширения браузера. У тебя что-то из этого глючит наверняка

Comment: Нет никаких расширений кроме гугл документы офлайн.
Фаервол включен. Все входящие соединения запрещены.
Исходящие пока лениво править. Может стоит оставить только 80 и 443? Плюс DNS и  DHCP порты

Answer (score 0):

HTTP как и SSH являются протоколами. Обмениваться сообщениями через HTTP используя SSH звучит бредово. Возможно, ты имеешь в виду атаку "человек по середине", то есть, кто-то перехватывает твой пакет и меняет информацию в нем перед тем, как он достигнет конечного пользователя, но facebook не доступен по HTTP, по моему он принудительно использует HTTPS.

Учитывая то, как ты поставил свой вопрос, навряд ли кто-то сможет на него ответить в такой формулировке. Ты можешь выполнить команду tracert или traceroute в зависимости от той операционной системы на которой ты сидишь. Там увидишь весь путь запроса от тебя к конечному серверу. Вот пример маршрута следования пакетов от меня до vk.com:

[image: tracert до vk.com]

То есть сначала мы видим мой локальный ip адрес, потом два ip моего провайдера, потом мы встречаем еще два адреса, которые отказываются обрабатывать любой icmp пакет, ну и ip адрес одного из сервера vk.com.

Если ты используешь facebook проживая на территории РФ, то само собой будет какой-то прокси стоять. В общем можешь покапать в эту сторону, а можешь просто сменить провайдера (да с телефона зайди) и посмотреть что будет. И используй HTTPS.

Comment: Спасибо. На самом деле я опечатался.  Я хотел написать SSL, а не SSH.
Но ощущение скрипача посередине не проходит. 
Я могу увидеть маршрут, но что это в конечном итоге даст, если скрипач сидит у провайдера или в самом фейсбук?
Как временная мера - сменил DNS сервер

Comment: Провайдеру не нужно подменять тебе символы, они такой ерундой заниматься не будут. Дешевые прокси сервера могут пихать свою рекламу в пакет, которая, условно, будет всплывать внизу экрана и предлагать кое что увеличить, но заниматься подменой символов при вводе это просто балавство какое-то. Что же касается самого facebook, то это уже совсем бред по двум причинам, первая - это facebook, вторая - это конечный пункт, ради чего им что-то менять?)) Смените провайдера и попробуйте воспроизвести проблему

Comment: Буду предельно честен. Недоброжелателей полно. 
Причина - мой веб ресурс.
См. здесь: http://78.26.164.4

Comment: Очень мало информации. Не могу связать что к чему. Дам пару советов касательно веб ресурса и побегу. Во первых настройте ns адреса на хостинге, не получайте информацию напрямую на ip адрес, во вторых перейдите на https. Принудительно делайте переход туда. lets encrypt в помощь. Погуглите

Comment: Спасибо. Но вопрос не в безопасности веб сервера.  Уже лет  5 работает без проблем. Я даже не собирался использовать https на нем. Не хочу покупать сертификаты. А самосгенерированные браузеры не любят.
По поводу адресов напрямую. Мой способ кажется безопаснее, так-как никто не подменит айпи доменного имени на зеркало с цензурой.
Проблема именно в чатах соц. сетей похоже. 
Буду признателен за любую подсказку

Comment: Тут я уже бессилен. Единственное, что могу посоветовать - это развернуть свой вопрос на столько, на сколько это вообще возможно в принципе и дать там максимум информации по проблему

Comment: Ну вот тут маршрут: http://78.26.164.4/images/ip.png
Все, что приходит на ум - это искать софту, которая поможет увидеть - было ли это действительно нажатие клавиши ошибочное, или что-то пришло по сети